# Typo3 8.7.3 ExtBase - Individual MySQL Query in Repository

Tags: php, mysql, typo3, extbase

i am currently encounter a problem which is what i think connected to database cardinality and Typo3 not recognizing it.

I've got a project model which has different preevaluations, evaluations and mentorings connected with 1:n relationship. So i want to get all the projects where a user is connected to in either one of these models. The user for the different models can be different or the same, but i want to get the project only once back. Since i read in the documentation of the typo3 extbase, the cardinality is implicitly found by typo3 when i use individual db queries.

The evaluations, preevaluations and mentorings are set in the TCA with the type "inline" in a custom column declaration.

The function I am trying to use is that one over here:

```
public function findOwnedProjects($filters,$aSorting = NULL, $aSearch = NULL)
{
    $user = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->user;
    $userId = $user['uid'];

    $query = $this->createQuery();

    $orCondition[] = $query->equals('preEvaluations.frontendUser', $userId);
    $orCondition[] = $query->equals('evaluations.frontendUser', $userId);
    $orCondition[] = $query->equals('mentorings.frontendUser', $userId);
    $orCondition[] = $query->equals('projectlead', $userId);

    $condition[] = $query->logicalOr($orCondition);

    $condition[] = $query->equals("type", 'project', false);

    $query->matching($query->logicalAnd($condition));

    if (!empty($aSorting)) {
      $sSorting = $aSorting['order'] == 'asc' ? \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\QueryInterface::ORDER_ASCENDING : \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\QueryInterface::ORDER_DESCENDING;
      $sSortBy = strip_tags(trim($aSorting['sortBy']));
      $query->setOrderings(array($sSortBy => $sSorting));
    }

    return $query->execute();
}
```

But this is returning duplicate projects when there is more than one preevaluation or so connected to the project. I tried var_dumping the SQL statement which is generated and could see there is no DISTINCT in use. That is the whole problem i think and i don't see a solution so far.

I am not a typo3 expert and just trying to figure out what the problem is. If you got any idea what i might have missed, please answer this question.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would try with the `$query->contains` method like that :

```
$orCondition[] = $query->contains('preEvaluations.frontendUser', $userId);
$orCondition[] = $query->contains('evaluations.frontendUser', $userId);
$orCondition[] = $query->contains('mentorings.frontendUser', $userId);
$orCondition[] = $query->contains('projectlead', $userId);
```